# How to blur() consistently cross browsers?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

There is a difference in rendering of blur effect in Firefox and Chrome.

For some small value like `filter: blur(30px)` Chrome and Firefox produce nearly the same Gaussian blur.

But for a big value like `filter: blur(200px)` those browsers have a very noticeable difference.

Here is an example of that in 4 images: (FF left, Chrome right)

(Website shown is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function I edited maximum of slider to be 200 in devtools)

*0px blur: same*

[image: zero blur]

*30px blur: same*

[image: thirty blur]

*100px blur: same-ish*

[image: hundred blur]

*200px blur: different*

[image: two hundred blur]

It looks as if Firefox applies blur only inside the original dimensions, whereas Chrome enlarges the blur application area and *leaks* the "whiteness" from outside to inside. That observation may be wrong though.

My question to SO is "How can I get a consistent blur effect cross browsers?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox limits the css blur filter to 100px or 300px depending on if it is applied via hardware or software rendering which depends on the hardware of the user.
This is because of the performance impact the gaussian blur effect has. More info: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1530810

Chrome has a limit as well, I think it is 500px.

However if you want to go over that limit and ignore any performance problems you can implement a gaussian blur effect within a canvas element. Via for example this WebGL shader: https://github.com/Jam3/glsl-fast-gaussian-blur
That'll get you a consisent look regardless of the performance impact.